# APIM 1.9.1 - Using get method for send token

Tags: wso2, token, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 1.9.1 and I know that is necessary send token by HEADER Method for request any APIs.

But in OpenLayer 3 is not possible put any request at header. For solve it, I think that is better send the token by GET method. Is it possible do it using WSO2 API Manager?

Thanks.

Comment: Will be OK if you don't need that Basic Authentication to invoke your API?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I need some autentication where I can send the token by get.